# Time travel to the past in binary black hole system

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-travel

I just saw [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmWO4Vtk-s8) (only 3 mins long) of Neil deGrasse Tyson explaining what happens when two black holes collide. He says that when the black holes are rotating around each other, there exists a path that you could follow that would cause you to travel back in time. Any chance that someone could explain this in an intuïtive way to me? I just finished my 1st bachelor physics, to give you an idea of my knowledge. I also understand the basics of special relativity.

Comment: This is a general relativity issue and it would be more helpful if you could find the research that Tyson references in the video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he's being a bit loose with the truth.

There is a solution to Einstein's equations due to Kramer and Neugebauer$^1$ that describes two black holes rotating around each other. Well, sort of. I confess I don't really understand the details, but the two black holes have to be separated by a massless rod, so at best it would only be an approximation to a real binary black hole.

Anyhow, the setup can be described in a way analogous to a rotating cylinder, and consequently it warps spacetime in the same way that a [Tipler cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipler_cylinder) does. Since the geometry near a Tipler cylinder has closed timelike curves that means the KN metric also has closed timelike curves.

However I was under the impression that Hawking had proved no **finite** system can have closed timelike curves unless exotic matter is involved (the Tipler cylinder is infinite) so I don't see how the KN metric can manage the trick. Maybe it's the artificial constraint of the massless bar connecting the two black holes. If so, this means that a real black hole binary **will not** have any closed timelike curves associated with it, and therefore no time travel. Sorry!

$^1$ Kramer D. and Neugebauer G., "The Superposition of Two Kerr Solutions," 1980, 
Phys. Lett. A, 75, 259 - I don't think this is available online.

Comment: Oh, there will still be time travel. Just not to the past.